# for statements, <=, javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm doing a project on CodeAcademy and this part requires a for statement.
This is my code:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
console.log(i);
```

Basically, I am just wondering, since the second condition "`i <=20`" is telling it when to stop repeating the code, why does it not stop straight away.  Since 1 is less than 20.

I would think that it should be `i = 20` and when `i = 20` it stops.
But that doesn't seem to be the case.  Which is really confusing me.

Comment: never ever do this: `for (i ...` do `for (var i ...` unless you really want to define a variable global (wich is bad)

Answer (score 3):

The middle statement is not telling when to stop the loop, it's telling when it should *continue*. As long as it evaluates to true, the loop repeats.

Comment: Oh!  Thankyou!  haha
I guess they didn't explain it correctly.  Makes more sense!

Answer (score 2):

You are confused because you assume the second argument tells it when to stop, this is incorrect, it tells the loop how long to run, so in your case it tells the loop to 
  **run so long as i is less then or equal to 20**

See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp for more info

Answer (score 0):

because i is incrementing in i++ and <strike>it happens until i++ reaches a point where it meets the condition i<=20.</strike>

Read it as

keep incrementing i as i++  as long as i <=20

Comment: It's the exact opposite: keep incrementing i until i **is not** <= 20.

Comment: because _keep incrementing i as i++ until i<=20_ should be: keep incrementing i as i++ _as long as_ i<=20

Comment: i have corrected the statement, meant the same thing but written it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Good little sum up of a `for` loop right here:

```
for ( variable = startvalue; variable < endvalue; variable = variable + increment) {
    // code to be executed
}
```

The first part is a baseline for where the loop counter/index should start.

The middle part is saying *while* 'variable < endvalue` - keep looping.

`variable = variable + increment` written a lot just like `variable++;` keeps the loop going forward. as the variable gets incremented. (of course you can increment up/down, it all depends no what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

To help you reading a `for` loop consider always reading them like this:

```
for( initialization_expression; termination_expression; increment_expression ) {
  statements;
}
```

- The intialization_expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
- When the termination_expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
- The increment_expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

So to "read" it you can say:

1. Execute `initialization_expression`
2. Execute `statements` if `termination_expression` is true, else exit
3. Execute `increment_expression`
4. Go to 2.

Comment: I think saying it's the termination expression is what confused me in the first place.  It should be explain like this "This condition determines whether the code will go through again".  Or something.